# Gmagick thumbnail for multi-page PDF

Tags: php, pdf, graphicsmagick, gmagick

I'm attempting to create a thumbnail of a multi-page PDF document using Gmagick, however I only want the first page of the PDF, not all of them.

```
$thumb = new Gmagick();
$thumb->readImage("/path/to/file/document.pdf");
$thumb->setImageFormat('JPG');
$thumb->thumbnailimage(198, 255);
$thumb->writeImage("/path/to/file/document.jpg");
$thumb->destroy();
```

This code works, however instead of creating just 1 image 'document.jpg' it creates 'document.jpg.0', 'document.jpg.1', 'document.jpg.2', etc. for all of the PDF pages. I could go and delete all the additional pages and rename the first image just 'document.jpg' but that seems a bit hacky to me.

Is there a way to designate just the first page of the PDF? I can't seem to find anything, and Gmagick's documentation seems to be lacking.

Comment: IIRC command-line imagemagick accepts `/path/to/file/document.pdf[0]`, maybe it works in GM as well

Answer (score 1):

Pekka is right. GraphicsMagick - just like ImageMagick - accepts the special pdf file name notation `filename.pdf[0]` which would render only the first page, `filename.pdf[1]` for the second page, and so on.